# Allow for multiple classes

Tags: jquery, html, css, class

I'm working with [jQuery maphighlight](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/) and I need a little more functionality out of the groupBy feature.

I need to replace this

```
areas = map.find('area['+area_options.groupBy+'="'+$(this).attr(area_options.groupBy)+'"]');
```

with something that allows one class **or** the other. Currently if I use it to group by class it won't match an element with `class="opt1"` to and element with `class="opt1 opt4"`. I need the element "opt1 opt4" to match all "opt1" and "opt4" elements and vice versa.

So far I've got a variable that splits the classes
`groupClasses = $(this).attr(area_options.groupBy).split(" ");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make more than one thing in a selector, you would use a comma.

```
$("#MyDiv").find(".one,.two");
```

That would find elements inside of MyDiv that have the class of one or two.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use a selector to the `groupBy` attribute like: `.opt1,.opt4`, at least this is the implementation I see in the code. In this demonstration page http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_features.html the `.square2` has a groupBy attribute set like this

```
data-maphilight='{"groupBy":".group"}'
```